# a preg_match not working on 7.1.11, but on other version working

Tags: php, preg-match

I have some code , it is not working on php 7.1.11, but on other version working, why?

The result:

7.1.11

```
>>> $final_pattern = "/^(?:(?:33|55|81)\d{8}|(?:2(?:0[01]|2[1-9]|3[1-35-8]|4[13-9]|7[1-689]|8[1-578]|9[467])|3(?:1[1-79]|[2458][1-9]|7[1-8]|9[1-5])|4(?:1[1-57-9]|[24-6][1-9]|[37][1-8]|8[1-35-9]|9[2-689])|5(?:88|9[1-79])|6(?:1[2-68]|[234][1-9]|5[1-3689]|6[12457-9]|7[1-7]|8[67]|9[4-8])|7(?:[13467][1-9]|2[1-9]|5[13-9]|8[1-69]|9[17])|8(?:2[13-689]|3[1-6]|4[124-6]|6[1246-9]|7[1-378]|9[12479])|9(?:1[346-9]|2[1-4]|3[2-46-8]|5[1348]|[69][1-9]|7[12]|8[1-8]))\d{7})/ui"
=> "/^(?:(?:33|55|81)\d{8}|(?:2(?:0[01]|2[1-9]|3[1-35-8]|4[13-9]|7[1-689]|8[1-578]|9[467])|3(?:1[1-79]|[2458][1-9]|7[1-8]|9[1-5])|4(?:1[1-57-9]|[24-6][1-9]|[37][1-8]|8[1-35-9]|9[2-689])|5(?:88|9[1-79])|6(?:1[2-68]|[234][1-9]|5[1-3689]|6[12457-9]|7[1-7]|8[67]|9[4-8])|7(?:[13467][1-9]|2[1-9]|5[13-9]|8[1-69]|9[17])|8(?:2[13-689]|3[1-6]|4[124-6]|6[1246-9]|7[1-378]|9[12479])|9(?:1[346-9]|2[1-4]|3[2-46-8]|5[1348]|[69][1-9]|7[12]|8[1-8]))\d{7})/ui"
>>> $search=9381392375
=> 9381392375
>>> preg_match($final_pattern, $search, $groups, 256);
=> 0
>>> $groups
=> []
>>> preg_match($final_pattern, $search, $groups);
=> 0
>>> $groups
=> []
>>>
```

7.1.27

```
>>> $final_pattern = "/^(?:(?:33|55|81)\d{8}|(?:2(?:0[01]|2[1-9]|3[1-35-8]|4[13-9]|7[1-689]|8[1-578]|9[467])|3(?:1[1-79]|[2458][1-9]|7[1-8]|9[1-5])|4(?:1[1-57-9]|[24-6][1-9]|[37][1-8]|8[1-35-9]|9[2-689])|5(?:88|9[1-79])|6(?:1[2-68]|[234][1-9]|5[1-3689]|6[12457-9]|7[1-7]|8[67]|9[4-8])|7(?:[13467][1-9]|2[1-9]|5[13-9]|8[1-69]|9[17])|8(?:2[13-689]|3[1-6]|4[124-6]|6[1246-9]|7[1-378]|9[12479])|9(?:1[346-9]|2[1-4]|3[2-46-8]|5[1348]|[69][1-9]|7[12]|8[1-8]))\d{7})/ui"
=> "/^(?:(?:33|55|81)\d{8}|(?:2(?:0[01]|2[1-9]|3[1-35-8]|4[13-9]|7[1-689]|8[1-578]|9[467])|3(?:1[1-79]|[2458][1-9]|7[1-8]|9[1-5])|4(?:1[1-57-9]|[24-6][1-9]|[37][1-8]|8[1-35-9]|9[2-689])|5(?:88|9[1-79])|6(?:1[2-68]|[234][1-9]|5[1-3689]|6[12457-9]|7[1-7]|8[67]|9[4-8])|7(?:[13467][1-9]|2[1-9]|5[13-9]|8[1-69]|9[17])|8(?:2[13-689]|3[1-6]|4[124-6]|6[1246-9]|7[1-378]|9[12479])|9(?:1[346-9]|2[1-4]|3[2-46-8]|5[1348]|[69][1-9]|7[12]|8[1-8]))\d{7})/ui"
>>> $search=9381392375
=> 9381392375
>>> preg_match($final_pattern, $search, $groups, 256);
=> 1
>>> $groups                                                                                                                            => [
     [
       "9381392375",
       0,
     ],
   ]
>>>
```

The code:

```php
$final_pattern = "/^(?:(?:33|55|81)\d{8}|(?:2(?:0[01]|2[1-9]|3[1-35-8]|4[13-9]|7[1-689]|8[1-578]|9[467])|3(?:1[1-79]|[2458][1-9]|7[1-8]|9[1-5])|4(?:1[1-57-9]|[24-6][1-9]|[37][1-8]|8[1-35-9]|9[2-689])|5(?:88|9[1-79])|6(?:1[2-68]|[234][1-9]|5[1-3689]|6[12457-9]|7[1-7]|8[67]|9[4-8])|7(?:[13467][1-9]|2[1-9]|5[13-9]|8[1-69]|9[17])|8(?:2[13-689]|3[1-6]|4[124-6]|6[1246-9]|7[1-378]|9[12479])|9(?:1[346-9]|2[1-4]|3[2-46-8]|5[1348]|[69][1-9]|7[12]|8[1-8]))\d{7})/ui"

$search=9381392375

preg_match($final_pattern, $search, $groups, 256);
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: can you provide preg_last_error() for 7.1.1?

Comment: cause only one bug report found in version diff about pcre is that - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74183

Comment: @myxaxa, I see the bug issue, how can I solve this problem, just upgrade the php version ?

Comment: well, yeap:) if it's working - why not?:) maybe better to upgrade to 7.3

Comment: @myxaxa ok, thx